# Overset and Underset in equation

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to the following equation :
[image]

Unfortunately, I am not able to write the letter and number directly below pi and summation symbol. How can I fix this? So far I have this :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{equation}
     \Bigg(\overset{n}{\Pi_{j=1}}f_j\Bigg) \Bigg(\overset{nME}{\sum_{i=1}}P_{ME(i)}.C_{FME(i)}.SFC_{ME(i)}\Bigg) + (P_{AE}.C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE})+\Bigg(\Bigg(\overset{n}{\Pi_{j=1}}f_j.\overset{nPTI}{\sum_{i=1}}P_{PTI(i)}- \overset{neff}{\sum_{i=1}}f_{eff(i)}.P_{AEeff(i)}\Bigg) C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE}\Bigg) - \Bigg(\overset{neff}{\sum_{i=1}}f_{eff(i)}.P_{eff(i)}.C_{FME}.SFC_{ME}\Bigg)
\end{equation}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\prod\limits` and `\sum\limits` instead of oversetting a pi ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need for `\overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\Bigg(\prod_{j=1}^n f_j\Bigg) 
    \Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{nME}P_{ME(i)}.C_{FME(i)}.SFC_{ME(i)}\Bigg) + 
        (P_{AE}.C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE})+ \\
    \Bigg(\Bigg(\prod_{j=1}^n f_j.\sum_{i=1}^{nPTI} P_{PTI(i)}-
    \sum_{i=1}{neff}f_{eff(i)}.P_{AEeff(i)}\Bigg) C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE}\Bigg) -\\ 
    \Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{neff}f_{eff(i)}.P_{eff(i)}.C_{FME}.SFC_{ME}\Bigg)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\Biggl` and `\Biggr`, not the unadorned `\Bigg`

Answer (score 4):

1. You should use semantic macros, i.e. write what you mean, not how it should look like, i.e. use `\prod` instead of `\Pi` to write products.
2. You can simply set the limits of `\sum` and `\prod` as `\prod_{lower}^{upper}` like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \prod_{j = 1}^n f_j \sum_{i = 1}^n g_i
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment above, you should not use `\overset` here. Assuming `eff` stands for effective, I would typeset it upright. You are loading `mathtools`, so you can use `\MoveEqLeft` to obtain

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\MoveEqLeft    \left(\prod^{n}_{j=1}f^{(j)}\right) 
     \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_{ME}}P_{ME}^{(i)}\cdot C_{FME}^{(i)}
     \cdot SFC_{ME}^{(i)}\right) 
     +(P_{AE}\cdot C_{FAE}\cdot SFC_{AE})\notag\\
&{}  
     +\left(\left(\prod^n_{j=1}f_j\cdot
     \sum^{n_{PTI}}_{i=1}P_{PTI}^{(i)}
     -   \sum^{n_\mathrm{eff}}_{i=1}f_\mathrm{eff}^{(i)}
     \cdot P_{AE,\mathrm{eff}}^{(i)}\right) 
     C_{FAE}\cdot SFC_{AE}\right) \notag\\
&{}  
     - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_\mathrm{eff}}
     f_\mathrm{eff}^{(i)}\cdot P_\mathrm{eff}^{(i)}
     \cdot C_{FME}\cdot SFC_{ME}\right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]